# emacs doc-view new frame

Tags: emacs, latex

I am new to Emacs and presently I am using it heavily for LaTeXing.
Please help me out with the following customizations:

1. How to scroll continuously in `doc-view-mode`? I have

   ```
   (setq doc-view-continuous t)
   ```

   in my `.emacs` file. This enables scrolling through the pages, however, the pages "jump" to the next one. I do not like reading to the bottom of the screen. Is it possible to resolve it?
2. I invoke doc-view using <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> and the PDF loads into a new window. Is it possible to load it in a new frame?
3. I have used

   ```
   (menu-bar-mode -1)
   (tool-bar-mode -1)
   (scroll-bar-mode -1)
   ```

   in my `.emacs` file. This works fine. However, the first line is just below the top screen. Can I create some margin ONLY on top?
4. How do I copy/paste from Emacs to other application, like a browser? I couldn't copy the code above using <kbd>C-w</kbd> in Emacs and then <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd> in Iceweasel (browser). I had to use Kate, sadly. (This I realized while typing this question!)

Regards,
Saurav Agarwal

Answer (score 0):

1. You should be able to scroll "line by line" with <kbd>C-n</kbd> and <kbd>C-p</kbd>.
2. I do not know that mode (I use `tex-mode`), but what you probably want is to find out how <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> is invoking doc-view and use it with `other-window`, for example:

   ```
   (defun new-frame-dvi-file ()
     (interactive)
     (split-window-right)
     (other-window 1)
     (tex-view))
   ```
3. I could not find anything that sets a top margin ONLY, but found this:

   ```
   (set-frame-parameter nil 'internal-border-width 10)
   ```
4. You can share clipboards with this:

   ```
   (setq x-select-enable-clipboard t)
   ```

Anyway, even if it sounds really boring, sometimes it is really useful to take a look at the manual. Sometimes you don't need to read it all and you can find the answer quickly ;-)

Hope it helps!

Comment: 1. I am able to scroll but what I wanted was that the scroll be continuous, in the sense that it should not jump from one page to next.

2.I couldn't figure out the commands, I shall try to work on it.

3.Hoping for only top margin.

4. That helped.